# Know if there's a click event handler in my custom Svelte component

Tags: svelte

Is there a way to know if a click handler is set on my custom component? I want to add a CSS class to it that would add the `cursor: pointer;` style, but only if something is going to happen on click.

To illustrate, here is what could be the custom component:

```
<script>
  $: magic = ? // this is what I'm after
</script>

<div on:click
     class:pointer={magic}
>
  I might be clickable!
</div>

<style>
  .pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible due to the way events are implemented in svelte, however, it is not necessarily wrong to just use a prop if you need more fine-tuned control. i.e.

```html
<script>
export let onClick = () => {}
</script>

<button on:click={onClick}>Hello</button>
```

[Here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4249#issuecomment-573312191) is a comment about this topic from the svelte team

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle on click event in parent element then pass `magic` variable from the parent to your custom element via prop

or you can handle click event in your custom component then dispatch event to it's parent with [event forwarding](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-forwarding)